# How to fix an 'Object' may not respond to 'method' warning in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

In cocos2d, I'm trying to call a method on the Parent of a CocosNode. The app works fine, but I get an 'Object' may not respond to 'method' warning. The parent is a subclassed Cocos2d layer, so I'm guessing I need to cast parent somehow, but that generates fatal errors.

The method is like this

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint([newBrick boundingBox], touchedStartPoint)){
    [parent showChooser]; 
    return kEventHandled;
}
```

I've tried adding the following, but with no success...

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint([newBrick boundingBox], touchedStartPoint)){
    if([parent respondsToSelector:@selector(showChooser)]){
        [parent showChooser];
    }
    return kEventHandled;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `showChooser` is a method defined on your subclass, you should just be able to write:

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint([newBrick boundingBox], touchedStartPoint)){
    [(YourLayerSubclass*)parent showChooser];
    return kEventHandled;
}
```

or, if you want to be a little safer:

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint([newBrick boundingBox], touchedStartPoint)){
    if( [parent isKindOfClass:[YourLayerSubclass class]] ) {
        YourLayerSubclass *subclassParent = (YourLayerSubclass*)parent;
        [subclassParent showChooser];
        return kEventHandled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. If I may, why is the second option safer?

Comment: Because you're explicitly verifying that `parent` is an instance of the class you expect it to be, rather than just assuming it is.

Comment: ... which, if the assumption is wrong, could cause a crash. To end Otto's sentence. ;)